# Double calls from render

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a behavior that I don't understand.

With click on a simple link_to :remote=>true

#### wizards/index.html.erb

```
< %= link_to "bros", new_wizard_path(:idparent= >wz.idparent, :id= >wz.id), :remote => true %>
```

the controller prepare a new @wizard instance

#### controllers/wizards_controller.rb

```
def new  
  @wizard = Wizard.new  
  @wizard.idparent = flash[:id_of_parent]  
  flash[:id_of_parent] = nil  
  @wizard.idparent ||= params[:idparent]
end
```

and then calls corresponding js.erb,

#### wizards/new.js.erb

```
$('#divwizard').append('<div id="wizardnew"></div>');  
$('#wizardnew').html('<%=j (render(:partial => "wizards/new")) %>');
```

and this latter calls partial view

#### wizards/_new.html.erb

```
< %= render :partial = > "wizards/form" % >
```

#### wizards/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @wizard, :remote => true do |wiz| %>  
    < div class="edt_wiz" >  
    < div class="edt_wiz_pos" >  
<%= wiz.label :pos, :class => "pos"%>  
<%= wiz.text_field :pos %>
```

but on webrick log I read a double call at *_new.html.erb*

#### webrick log

```
Started GET "/wizards/new?id=126" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-21 19:08:51 +0200  
Processing by WizardsController#new as JS  
Parameters: {"id"=>"126"}  
Rendered wizards/_form.html.erb (5.7ms)  
Rendered wizards/_new.html.erb (6.9ms)  
Rendered wizards/_form.html.erb (6.3ms)  
Rendered wizards/_new.html.erb (7.1ms)  
Rendered wizards/new.js.erb (17.7ms)  
Completed 200 OK in 79ms (Views: 28.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

what's happen ?
who calls partial _new.html.erb twice ?

Someone can help me, please ? 
How can I debug this situation ?

**EDIT I**

I've omitted a piece of code (sorry!).
there is a **javascript condition !!**:

#### new.js.erb

```
if (something) { 
  $('#divwizard').append('<div id="wizardnew"></div>');  
  $('#wizardnew').html('<%=j (render(:partial => "wizards/new")) %>'); 
} else {   
  $('#otherdiv').append('<div id="wizard-other-new"></div>');  
  $('#wizard-other-new').html('<%=j (render(:partial => "wizards/new")) %>'); 
}
```

and erb, I think (?), execute both renders :partial because condition is in javascript, then executed after locally on browser.

I'm confused or is correct ?

Comment: AFAIK you should not use `flash` for storing temporary things, these have a very different purpose. Access your data via `params`.

Comment: Thanks @pduersteler; I came from other method on the same controller (with redirect_to) and using flash it's easy; I am considering your advice.Tnx

Answer (score 1):

This might be the case, because you don't pass the format between render calls.

Try adding `format: params[:format]` to the render calls inside the partials.

If that won't solve it, raising the params or the format specifically right next to the render calls in question might give you pointers as to what's going on.